# How I can insert a spinner selected item into SQL server for mobile app?

Tags: java, android, sql-server, spinner, crud

I am fetching the values from database into Spinner its working but I want to insert selected item from Spinner into database, how can I do this?

I'm using SQL server

I am using two Spinners and both Spinner's selected item should insert into database.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Spinner spinnercountry,spinnercountry1,spinnercountry2;
String ip, db, un, passwords;
Connection connect;
PreparedStatement stmt;
ResultSet rs;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    spinnercountry = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerdata);
    connect = CONN(un, passwords, db, ip);
    String query1 = "select proname from barang";
    try {
        connect = CONN(un, passwords, db, ip);
        stmt = connect.prepareStatement(query1);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();
        ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (rs.next()) {
            String id = rs.getString("proname");
            data.add(id);
        }
        String[] array = data.toArray(new String[0]);
        ArrayAdapter NoCoreAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, data);
        spinnercountry.setAdapter(NoCoreAdapter);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    spinnercountry.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String name = spinnercountry.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: Stop.  Do not connect directly to a db like this.  Doing this requires putting the password to the db in your app, which makes the db completely insecure.  Instead, write a webservice that sits in front of your app, and have the app use that.

Comment: Yeah im using password for my sql server, just i removed the code

Answer (score -1):

In side your spinner onItemSelected method use the following code

```
    String query1 = "INSERT INTO table_name VALUES ("+data.get(position)+")";
    stmt = connect.prepareStatement(query1);
    rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

Comment: NEVER use concatentation to put variables into a db.  That's a huge gaping security hole called SQL injection.

Comment: You can also use prepare statments. I was just trying to give a rought idea. Thanks @GabeSechan

Comment: Sorry my fault , i want to send all the spinner  i selected in in one button . like button send or add to database